# PStricks stopped working after 6-12-17 update

Tags: pstricks

PStricks stopped working after the latest update (6-12-17). I use XeLaTeX. Here is a very minimal example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\psset{yunit=1cm,xunit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(3,3)
\psline[linewidth=0.5pt,linestyle=solid](-2,2)(3,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

After compiling a file using XeLateX the following error shows up (it never showed up before):

MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.19: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

I have lots of pictures drawn in my documents using PStricks which now do not show up after compiling with XeLaTex. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I get a different error when trying to run `xelatex` on the code: `! Argument of \c@lor@to@ps has an extra }`

Answer (score 9):

The LaTeX team have been doing some work to update (rationalise) the various support files for graphics/colour in different engines. A few gremlins have come up during this process, and unfortunately this is one of them. A fix has already been sent to CTAN and should appear in TeX Live probably today: I can't be sure for MiKTeX but within a few days. If you *urgently* need to fix it then you can paste in the updated code in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\c@lor@arg#1{%
  \dimen@#1\p@
  \ifdim\dimen@<\z@\dimen@\maxdimen\fi
  \ifdim\dimen@>\p@
    \PackageError{color}{Argument `#1' not in range [0,1]}\@ehd
  \fi}
\def\color@gray#1#2{%
  \c@lor@arg{#2}%
  \edef#1{gray #2}%
  }
\def\color@cmyk#1#2{\c@lor@@cmyk#2\@@#1}
\def\c@lor@@cmyk#1,#2,#3,#4\@@#5{%
  \c@lor@arg{#4}%
  \c@lor@arg{#1}%
  \c@lor@arg{#2}%
  \c@lor@arg{#3}%
  \edef#5{cmyk #1 #2 #3 #4}%
  }
\def\color@rgb#1#2{\c@lor@@rgb#2\@@#1}
\def\c@lor@@rgb#1,#2,#3\@@#4{%
  \c@lor@arg{#1}%
  \c@lor@arg{#2}%
  \c@lor@arg{#3}%
  \edef#4{rgb #1 #2 #3}%
  }
\def\color@RGB#1#2{\c@lor@@RGB#2\@@#1}
\def\c@lor@@RGB#1,#2,#3\@@#4{%
 \c@lor@RGB@rgb{#1}\@tempa
 \c@lor@RGB@rgb{#2}\@tempb
 \c@lor@RGB@rgb{#3}\@tempc
 \c@lor@@rgb\@tempa,\@tempb,\@tempc\@@#4%
  }
\def\c@lor@RGB@rgb#1#2{%
  \dimen@#1\p@
  \divide\dimen@\@cclv
  \edef#2{\strip@pt\dimen@}}
\def\color@hsb#1#2{\c@lor@@hsb#2\@@#1}
\def\c@lor@@hsb#1,#2,#3\@@#4{%
  \c@lor@arg{#1}%
  \c@lor@arg{#2}%
  \c@lor@arg{#3}%
  \edef#4{hsb #1 #2 #3}%
  }
\def\color@named#1#2{\c@lor@@named#2,,\@@#1}
\def\c@lor@@named#1,#2,#3\@@#4{%
  \@ifundefined{col@#1}%
    {\PackageError{color}{Undefined color `#1'}\@ehd}%
  {\edef#4{ #1}}%
  }
\def\c@lor@to@ps#1 #2\@@{\csname c@lor@ps@#1\endcsname#2 \@@}
\def\c@lor@ps@#1 #2\@@{TeXDict begin #1 end}
\def\c@lor@ps@rgb#1\@@{#1 setrgbcolor}
\def\c@lor@ps@hsb#1\@@{#1 sethsbcolor}
\def\c@lor@ps@cmyk#1\@@{#1 setcmykcolor}
\def\c@lor@ps@gray#1\@@{#1 setgray}
\def\current@color{ Black}
\def\set@color{%
 \special{color push  \current@color
                          }\aftergroup\reset@color}
\def\reset@color{\special{%
        color pop}}
\def\set@page@color{\special{%
        background \current@color}}
\def\define@color@named#1#2{%
  \expandafter\let\csname col@#1\endcsname\@nnil}
      \def\no@page@color{\special{background \string"newpath clip}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\psset{yunit=1cm,xunit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(3,3)
\psline[linewidth=0.5pt,linestyle=solid](-2,2)(3,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I load `graphicx` *then* do the fix *then* load PStricks: you have to fix before PStricks gets loaded.

---

Details of the issue are as follows (for the experts). The `dvips` driver uses a notation for colour that is understood by PSTricks and where the 'interconversion' is carried out by a macro called `\c@lor@to@ps`. When you use XeTeX, there are two ways to describe colour: the `dvips` way and a 'native' `dvipdfmx` way.

In earlier releases, the `dvipdfmx` driver used it's own approach whilst `xetex` used the `dvips`-like one. However, as `xetex` and `dvipdfmx` are almost the same drivers, it made sense to bring them into line. The 'natural' way seemed to be to go for the native approach, so I copied the code from `dvipdfmx.def` to `xetex.def`. However, it turns out that the definition of `\c@lor@to@ps` in `dvipdfmx.def` was wrong, so that fails.

Two possible solutions presented themselves: fix `\c@lor@to@ps` in both `xetex.def` and `dvipdfmx.def` to work with 'native' colour specials, or simply switch all of them to `dvips`-like code. The latter approach avoids needing two separate sets of macros, so it's what we've done. Thus `xetex.def` dated `2017-06-13` or later will not have the issue.